# Issues with DOM parsing a partial HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have a WordPress site in which I'm manually instantiating a lazy load js script. I wanted to filter the_content to find any images and change the `src` attribute to `data-original` and at the same time add a class of `lazy` to the image.

I found this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60841/11169 which worked but by using the DOM parser I was getting a html declaration and extra body elements being rendered out.

This caused some character encoding issues.

I was able to get around this by modifying the code to force utf-8 during `loadHTML`, and then before returning the content I did a few `str_replace` to get rid of the doctype, html, head, and body elements.

```
function add_lazyload($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $content);


    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {

        // Get the original img source, place it in a data-original attr, and remove the source completely
        $image_source = $node->getAttribute('src');
        $node->setAttribute("data-original", $image_source);
        $node->removeAttribute('src');

        // Get the original classes, and add 'lazy'
        $old_class = $node->getAttribute('class');
        $new_class = $old_class . ' lazy';
        $node->setAttribute("class", $new_class);
    }

    $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
    $newHtml = str_replace('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">', null, $newHtml);
    $newHtml = str_replace('<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>', null, $newHtml);
    $newHtml = str_replace('</body></html>', null, $newHtml);
    // var_dump($newHtml);
    return trim($newHtml);
}
```

This does work, but seems wholly inefficient.

Perhaps I'd be better off with regular expressions to search and replace the content necessary, or perhaps there's some way to load partial HTML into DOM without having to worry about weird character encoding issues.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Why not do it in the template itself?

Comment: I want to automatically change any images embedded in WordPress post_content. So it seemed best to apply this as a `the_content` filter.

Answer (score 1):

To load the HTML you will have to add the elements to make it a full HTML document (to avoid the encoding issues). But saving is easier.

PHP 5.3.6 added a `$node` argument to `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`. You just need to provide the node you want to save.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$newHtml = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//body/node()') as $node) {
  $newHtml .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
return $newHtml;
```

DOMXPath allows you to use XPath fetch nodes from a DOM document. It is part of the DOM extension. `//body/node()` look for the `body` element node and fetches all child nodes, including text nodes.